# On the proof that (a,b) is of the same cardinality with [a,b].

Tags: real-analysis

A note: After some users answered the question, I realized that the problem in the argument  shown below is via typo error. I checked my pdf copy of Pugh's Analysis book and found that $j(x)=x/2+(a+b)/4$. Perhaps a printer error makes + sign a - sign.

I wish to prove that the interval $IO=(a,b)$ is of the same cardinality with the interval $IC=[a,b]$ where a and b are real numbers.

Here is Pugh's Real Mathematical Analysis proof using Schroeder-Bernstein Lemma.

Consider the map identity map $i:IO\to IC$ given by $i(x)=x$. It is easy to see that this mapping is an injection.

However for the mapping $j:IC\to IO$ given by $j(x)=x/2+(a-b)/4$ it is also easy to see that the mapping $j$ is injective. But my concern is about the well definedness of the function. Since if $x=(b-a)/4\in IC$ then j(x) might not be in IO since $(a-b)/4$ is negative. Am I right or wrong? If I am right how can we fix the proof? If I am wrong kindly help me understand the proof. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems a very strange $j(x)$ as you say.  The idea is to map $[a,b]$ to a closed interval of half the length centered on $\frac {a+b}2$, so I would write it as$j(x)=\frac {3a+b}4+\frac {x-a}{2}$.  It takes $a$ to $\frac {3a+b}4, b$ to $\frac {a+3b}4$ and is linear in between, so it is an injection.  All that needs to be fixed in the book version is changing the sign before $b$ to be plus.  That makes it equivalent to what I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a typo!
It would make a lot more sense if $j(x) = \frac{x}{2} + \frac{a+b}{2}$.
This map does nothing else then half the distance of $x$ to the center point of the interval $[a,b]$